Finding count of unique sequence made up of values spanned over several columns in Python
A contains columns x, y1, y2, y3 & y4.
I am interested in studying the {y1,y2,y3,y4} sequence w.r.t x.
To find unique {y1,y2,y3,y4} sequence occurring for each x, I do the following:
B = pd.DataFrame()
for x_temp in A['x'].unique():
    B = pd.concat([B, A[A['x'] == x_temp][['x','y1','y2','y3','y4']]])
B = B.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by=['x','y1','y2','y3','y4'])
del x_temp 

I want to introduce a new column called 'count' in B, which contains # of unique {y1,y2,y3,y4} that occurred for that specific x in A.
B['count'] = A.apply(lambda row: (A['y1'] == row['y1']) & (A['y2'] == row['y2']) & (A['y3'] == row['y3']) & (A['y4'] == row['y4']), axis=1).sum()

This works, however, it doesn't work if A or B has missing values. I want it to treat missing values also as a unique value.
Example:
A = pd.DataFrame({'x':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','1'],
                   'y1':['1','2','2',np.nan,'2',np.nan,'2','2','2','1'],
                   'y2':['2','1','2','2',np.nan,np.nan,'2','2','1','2'],
                   'y3':['1','1',np.nan,'2',np.nan,'2',np.nan,np.nan,'1','1'],
                   'y4':['2','2','2',np.nan,np.nan,'1','2','2','2','2']})

B = pd.DataFrame()
for x_temp in A['x'].unique():
    B = pd.concat([B, A[A['x'] == x_temp][['x','y1','y2','y3','y4']]])
B = B.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by=['x','y1','y2','y3','y4'])
del x_temp

B['count'] = A.apply(lambda row: (A['y1'] == row['y1']) & (A['y2'] == row['y2']) & (A['y3'] == row['y3']) & (A['y4'] == row['y4']), axis=1).sum()
print(B)

   x   y1   y2   y3   y4  count
0  1    1    2    1    2      2
1  1    2    1    1    2      2
2  1    2    2  NaN    2      0
3  1  NaN    2    2  NaN      0
8  2    2    1    1    2      2
6  2    2    2  NaN    2      0
4  2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN      0
5  2  NaN  NaN    2    1      0


Can you use .fillna() to replace missing values with a sentinel so the comparisons work?

Can you give an example of input that's causing this problem?

I'm assuming that this might work. However, it is taking more time. Thanks anyways.

@JoshuaRoy your output is unclear, why do you have 2 in the second row? There is only one 1/2/1/1/2, or do you also count that of x=2?

Assuming you want to count the values and then get the sum across the different xs, you could use:
cols = ['x','y1','y2','y3','y4']

out = (A[cols].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False)
       .reset_index(name='count')
       .sort_values(by=cols, na_position='last')
       .assign(count=lambda x: x.groupby(cols[1:], dropna=False)
                               ['count'].transform('sum')
              )
      )

Output:
   x   y1   y2   y3   y4  count
0  1    1    2    1    2      2
1  1    2    1    1    2      2
2  1    2    2  NaN    2      3
3  1  NaN    2    2  NaN      1
4  2    2    1    1    2      2
5  2    2    2  NaN    2      3
6  2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN      1
7  2  NaN  NaN    2    1      1

If you want to set the rows with NaNs as 0:
cols = ['x','y1','y2','y3','y4']

out = (A[cols].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False)
       .reset_index(name='count')
       .sort_values(by=cols, na_position='last')
       .assign(count=lambda x: x.groupby(cols[1:])
                               ['count'].transform('sum')
                               .fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
              )
      )

Output:
   x   y1   y2   y3   y4  count
0  1    1    2    1    2      2
1  1    2    1    1    2      2
2  1    2    2  NaN    2      0
3  1  NaN    2    2  NaN      0
4  2    2    1    1    2      2
5  2    2    2  NaN    2      0
6  2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN      0
7  2  NaN  NaN    2    1      0

If you don't want to sum across the xs:
cols = ['x','y1','y2','y3','y4']

out = (A[cols].value_counts(dropna=False, sort=False)
       .reset_index(name='count')
       .sort_values(by=cols, na_position='last')
      )

Output:
   x   y1   y2   y3   y4  count
0  1    1    2    1    2      2
1  1    2    1    1    2      1
2  1    2    2  NaN    2      1
3  1  NaN    2    2  NaN      1
4  2    2    1    1    2      1
5  2    2    2  NaN    2      2
6  2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN      1
7  2  NaN  NaN    2    1      1


Wow...best method as it took <1sec to compute for my large dataset. Thanks.

@Joshua so which version did you need?

sorry for my late reply...the last one.

You can use notna() and isna(), create your masks and then apply():
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def _unique(A):
    B = pd.DataFrame()
    for el in A['x'].unique():
        B = pd.concat([B, A[A['x'] == el][['x', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']]])

    B = B.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by=['x', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'])

    def _mask(row):
        y1_mask = A['y1'].fillna('missing') == row['y1'] if pd.notna(row['y1']) else A['y1'].isna()
        y2_mask = A['y2'].fillna('missing') == row['y2'] if pd.notna(row['y2']) else A['y2'].isna()
        y3_mask = A['y3'].fillna('missing') == row['y3'] if pd.notna(row['y3']) else A['y3'].isna()
        y4_mask = A['y4'].fillna('missing') == row['y4'] if pd.notna(row['y4']) else A['y4'].isna()
        x_mask = A['x'] == row['x']

        return (x_mask & y1_mask & y2_mask & y3_mask & y4_mask).sum()

    B['count'] = B.apply(_mask, axis=1)

    return B


A = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'y1': [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 3],
    'y2': [2, 2, np.nan, 3, 3],
    'y3': [3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    'y4': [4, 4, 5, 5, np.nan]
})

print(_unique(A))


Prints
   x   y1   y2  y3   y4  count
0  1  1.0  2.0   3  4.0      2
2  2  2.0  NaN   4  5.0      1
4  2  3.0  3.0   4  NaN      1
3  2  NaN  3.0   4  5.0      1


Thanks, this works. However, this does take longer time than required. But, thanks for making this work.

Try:
def count_duplicated(g):
    vc = g.agg(tuple, axis=1).value_counts()
    out = pd.DataFrame([[*k, v] for k, v in vc.items()], columns=[*g.columns, "count"])
    return out


B = (
    A.groupby("x")
    .apply(count_duplicated, include_groups=False)
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
)
print(B)

Prints:
   x   y1   y2   y3   y4  count
0  1    1    2    1    2      2
1  1    2    1    1    2      1
2  1    2    2  NaN    2      1
3  1  NaN    2    2  NaN      1
4  2    2    2  NaN    2      2
5  2    2  NaN  NaN  NaN      1
6  2  NaN  NaN    2    1      1
7  2    2    1    1    2      1

